# Silverlight SQL Deployment

Tags: database, silverlight, deployment, installation, out-of-browser

I'm about to write an application in either Adobe Air or Silverlight, to run standalone, offline, on the desktop. It's a simple enough application that allows the user to enter text data and will then print formatted documents based on that information.  The obvious place to store all this relational data is in a database.  I believe Air comes with SQLite out of the box, so no problems there, but from what I can tell Silverlight doesn't. How does Silverlight handle installing an out of browser application that needs to access a local database? Does the user have to install SQL/SQLite first and then Silverlight, or is there some way that Silverlight can deploy that side of things itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Air, But Silverlight has IsolatedStorage for saving data on client-end and it has its own constrains. But if you want to have an application that can access local database why don't you try WPF(XBAP)?

This link can be helpful regarding SQLLite and Silverlight using IsolatedStorage.
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/118411/267135.aspx

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It looks like it's still a hack for Silverlight 3, but I understand 4 will have better access to the file system. From what I can see the user would still have to install SQLite and then install Silverlight afterwards, rather than a single installer doing it all. Not the best user experience.

I had a look at XBAP, but I need Mac support so that rules it out.

Looks like I might be using Air, damn was looking forward to getting into Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain silverlight isn't intended for... whatever it is you're trying to do.